# Sending email using Python with smtp

Tags: python, email, smtp

I am trying to write a module as part of my code to send out email. I have this code down which does not throw any exception but it does not deliver email as I expect. Can anyone help me point out any issue this code might have? Thanks in advance!

```
    """ before sending email with this code
    I start smtp server: 
    python -m smtpd -n -c DebuggingServer localhost:1025
    """
    #!/usr/bin/python -tt

    from email.mime.text import MIMEText
    from datetime import date
    import smtplib

    SMTP_SERVER = "localhost"
    SMTP_PORT = 1025

    EMAIL_TO = ["user385@dispostable.com"]
    EMAIL_FROM = "user383@testdomain.com"
    EMAIL_SUBJECT = "*Email Test*"

    DATE_FORMAT = "%d/%m/%Y"
    EMAIL_SPACE = ", "

    DATA='Test email sending feature in Python'

    def send_email():
        msg = MIMEText(DATA)
        msg['Subject'] = EMAIL_SUBJECT + " %s" %(date.today().strftime(DATE_FORMAT))
        msg['To'] = EMAIL_SPACE.join(EMAIL_TO)
        msg['From'] = EMAIL_FROM
        mail = smtplib.SMTP(SMTP_SERVER, SMTP_PORT)
        mail.sendmail(EMAIL_FROM, EMAIL_TO, msg.as_string())
        mail.quit()

    if __name__=='__main__':
        try:
            send_email()
        except Exception as e:
            import traceback;traceback.print_exc()
```

Thanks

Comment: Indentation is a little strange. Is it just the post or is there something else in the original?

Comment: @Javier I messed up indentation while copy+pasting, fixed it now

Answer (score 0):

hi can you remove the try except and run it again?

since youre using a gmail. can you try this one

```
import smtplib

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.starttls()
server.login("user383@gmail.com", "your-password-here")

msg = "YOUR MESSAGE!"
server.sendmail("user383@gmail.com", "user385@dispostable.com", msg)
server.quit()
```

Comment: I am not using gmail, that's just a sample gmail id which would not even matter. I want to send email from my localhost and not using gmail.